# Split string with strtok (nested)

Tags: c++, arduino

I use an arduino MEGA to parse a the param part of an url. 
It should not matter how the order of the parameters are. I have following code and I tried that with strtok.

```
char text[] = "ssid=SSID&pwd=PASSWORD&userId=1234"
```

and will split in

```
ssid=SSID
pwd=PASSWORD
userId=1234
```

and split it again in key and values

```
ssid
SSID

pwd
PASSWORD

userId
1234
```

I tried to use strtok for the first split.

```
  char *ptr;
  ptr = strtok(params, "&");

  while (ptr != NULL) {
    Serial.println(urlParam);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, "&");
  }
```

and the output is as expected:

Output:

```
ssid=SSID
pwd=PASSWORD
userId=1234
```

then the next split:

```
  char *ptr;
  ptr = strtok(params, "&");

  while (ptr != NULL) {

    char *paramKey;
    char *paramValue;
    paramKey = strtok(ptr, "=");
    Serial.println(paramKey);

    if (paramKey == 'ssid'){
      paramValue = strtok(NULL, "=");
      Serial.println(paramValue);       

      ssidName = paramValue;
    }

    if (paramKey == 'pwd'){
      ...
    }

    if (paramKey == 'userId'){
      ...
    }       

    ptr = strtok(NULL, "&");
  }
```

But the output is just

```
ssid
SSID
```

Looks like the loop is not working properly.

Where do I make the mistake?
Is there any other way to resolve this string?

Comment: you can't switch back and forth between different strtok targets like this -- you have to do all of the first strtok before you use strtok again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `strtok` function uses an internal static variable to keep track of its current state.  When you use the function for multiple different substrings interleaved like you're doing, you step on the internal state.

You need to instead use `strtok_r`, which uses an external variable to keep track of state.

```
  char *ptr, *sav1 = NULL;
  ptr = strtok_r(params, "&", &sav1);    // outer strtok_r, use sav1

  while (ptr != NULL) {

    char *paramKey;
    char *paramValue;
    char *sav2 = NULL;
    paramKey = strtok_r(ptr, "=", &sav2);   // inner strtok_r, use sav2
    Serial.println(paramKey);

    if (!strcmp(paramKey, "ssid")) {
      paramValue = strtok_r(NULL, "=", &sav2);  // inner strtok_r, use sav2
      Serial.println(paramValue);       

      ssidName = paramValue;
    }

    if (!strcmp(paramKey, "pwd")) {
      ...
    }

    if (!strcmp(paramKey, "userId")) {
      ...
    }       

    ptr = strtok_r(NULL, "&", &sav1);    // outer strtok_r, use sav1
  }
```

Not related to the parsing issue, you also can't compare strings with `==`.  You need to use `strcmp` instead, and string constants are surrounded in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: The solution works great. Many Thanks!!!
strcmp should i known, my mistake. Strtok_r is new to me, so I have to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have *three* problems:

1. The first is that you use implementation-specific multi-character literals like e.g. `'ssid'`, when you should be using strings like `"ssid"`.
2. The second problem is that you use `==` to compare strings. That's almost impossible to get to work, as then you compare the *pointers* instead of the string contents. To compare strings you need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).
3. The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is not reentrant. You can't have multiple `strtok` parsings going simultaneously. Either separate the steps, or use `strtok_s` (or `strtok_r` if such a function is available).

Comment: Or don't use `strtok` family at all. There are much better ways to split strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct split_result {
    char first_part[64];
    char second_part[64];
};

split_result return_left(char splitter, const char *str);

int main() {
    /*
        ssid=SSID
        pwd=PASSWORD
        userId=1234
    */
    char *str = "ssid=109304905995";
    split_result result = return_left('=', str);

    printf("first part: %s \n second part: %s\n", result.first_part, result.second_part);

    return 0;
}

split_result return_left(char splitter, const char *str) {
    int i = 0;

    split_result split_ptr;

    while (str[i] != 0) {
        //we found splitter
        if ((char)str[i] == splitter) {
            //remove first half
            strncpy_s(split_ptr.first_part, str, (int)(&str[i]-str));
            break;
        }

        //we need to remove second half now
        i++;
    }
    strcpy_s(split_ptr.second_part, &str[i+1]);
    return split_ptr;
}
```

I hope this will be helpful to anyone.